# Access logger from multiple types of projects, one config file

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a solution that is a combination of WCF, console applications, services, and ASMX projects. I need a way to have a single log4net config file for all of these projects. I cannot inject a logger into these classes. I'm thinking of a central log manager that wraps log4net.

What's a good way to provide a log manager that allows this?

Also, I also don't want to be reading the config file all the time. I'd rather load it up once the first time it's needed. Especially since this will mean reading it each time an ASMX page is loaded.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service, then all your projects can log to the service. You will only have one configuration and change all on configuration at one place.